# Trim function causes date format change

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly, important to note that I'm in the UK so standard date format is dd/mm/yyyy

In a A1, I have a date: 02/05/2017 (dd/mm/yyyy)

I can confirm this in the immediate window:

```
?CLng(Range("A1").Value)
42857
```

Now, if I do the following:

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

you can probably guess, nothing happens - the date is still 02/05/2017 and the numeric value is still 42857

But if I use trim with it:

```
Range("A1").Value = Trim(Range("A1").Value)
```

The date is changed to 05/02/2017. This isn't just formatting - the numeric value has also changed to 42771.

---

What is it about the `Trim()` method that causes the date to be read in US format and then converted back to UK format with a new date value? Is this a bug?

Comment: This is mostly just an educated guess: Excel uses the US English format as "international" or "token" format. When you parse a date with .Value, it is read as literal text. If you run it through any VBA function, the literal text is recognized as a date (wrongly assumed to be in the "standard" US format). So when you write it back, the wrong date gets written into the cell. Could you try `?Trim(Range("A1").Value)` to see what it returns inside the immediate? Try using the `.Value2`, or try using ISO standard formats (yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: `Trim(Range("A1").Value)` returns the correct date - I know VBA uses US instead of the OS region, but I'm not asking it to convert anything to date so it shouldn't have any effect here. It only seems to change when the value is written back to the cell _after_ being trimmed. The trimmed value itself is actually still correct

Comment: Trim is a text function, its output is a text. That text is recognized by Excel as a date in US English format. This would mean that any text function would yield the same result, like: `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value & ""` Same happens with `?cdate(Trim("02/05/2017"))`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is there is a date --> text and a text --> date conversion silently happening, and the cell formatting or OS region setting is not taken into consideration on the second conversion.

Comment: Yes - just did some more tests, because Trim returns an implicit string and VBA ignores regional settings it's being interpreted as US format before being written back to the cell. If you want to post an answer I'll accept, please note the terminology though it's actually VBA that defaults to US format - not Excel.

Comment: IF the date is correctly recognised by Excel, there is no reason to "trim" it. If your problem was that the cell contained a string that looked like a date, then trim would be fine but you would need another explicit conversion to an actual date. If the problem is how the date if formatted, then the solution is to change the format dates are displayed in not to apply string functions to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion in comments:

The default or "token" format in VBA (not Excel itself, as Macro Man rightly pointed out) is US English - regardless of regional settings or cell formatting.

When you do VBA text functions on a date, the output of those functions are in text format. So the result of `Trim(Range("A1").Value)` is a string. This string happens to resemble a proper US date, so when you insert it into a cell, Excel recognizes it as a US date.

So two implicit conversions happen. The first happens when you read the cell contents and pass it to `trim()`: date->text conversion; the second happens when you write it back to an Excel cell: text->date conversion. The second conversion has no information about the format, so it assumes US English.

(You should be able to achieve the same result with any text function, not just `trim()`.)

Answer (score -1):

I found out that if you add `"'"` before the date, the date is not altered.

```
Range("A1").Value = "'"&Trim(Range("A1").Value)
```