# VBA Changing Dates from UK to US

Tags: vba, excel

I'm transferring data from one spreadsheet to another - I have confirmed that in spreadsheet A the value held is '42800' which is 06/03/2017.

When I run my VBA which simply transfers Range("A1").Value to Sheets("Example").Range("A1").Value. Obviously this is a simplified example, but why when the date is stored as that value is the data transferring to the new sheet with the date of '42889' which is 03/06/2017 (the American format).

Should the date of 42800 not be placed in the new sheet regardless? Why is it making this formatting change?

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example").Cells(rowx, 12).Value = Validate_Date(wbBlank.Worksheets("A15").Range("J15").Value)
```

And Validate Date is

```
Function Validate_Date(s1 As String) As String

    If (IsDate(s1)) Then
        Validate_Date = s1

    Else
        Validate_Date = ""
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: It's not a formatting change, it's a *value* change. Show us your code, right now your question can't be answered. See [mcve].

Comment: Added the code to the example. Date in 'Example' is 42800 or 06/03/2017. Comfirmed as 'English (UK) dd/mm/yyyy'

Comment: So `wbBlank.Worksheets("A15").Range("J15").Value` can be either empty or a date, correct?

Comment: related?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304709/trim-function-causes-date-format-change

Comment: Treat dates as dates. You're telling the VBA runtime to perform a bunch of implicit conversions for you, and in doing so it's making assumptions. Then you send the string back to Excel, and now it's Excel doing implicit conversions and making assumptions. Treat dates as dates, you'll avoid the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - the cell in 'Example' is empty. The cell in wbBlank.Worksheets("A15").Range("J15").Value is the date value that is 42800

Comment: NEVER put a `Date` into a `String`. Be it in VBA, SQL, PHP, C#, Java, or anything. Treat dates as dates; no ifs, no buts. A `String` can only ever *represent* a date, not *be* a date.

Comment: Thank you for your responses @Mat'sMug - can I clarify where the string becomes involved; is the cell with the date (of the value 42800) '.Value' not the value of the cell? Or do I need to explicitly tell excel that the value in that cell is a Date? (I thought the Validate_Date checking whether IsDate was true was enough, but I am new to this)

Comment: Indeed, 42800 is the `Value` of the cell. But `TypeName(wbBlank.Worksheets("A15").Range("J15").Value)` will return `Date`, so VBA sees that 42800 as a `Date` (or `Double`, if it's empty) - and when you pass it to `Validate_Date` as a `String` parameter, VBA needs to perform a type conversion so that `Validate_Date` can work with a `String`. Change the parameter type to `Range` (pass the range, not its value), and work with the cell's real value instead of a representation of it. Check for `IsError` and `IsBlank`, and return a `Date`, not a `String`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a legend. That makes a lot more sense to me now :)

Comment: lol, no problem. I posted an answer that actually works *exactly* as your intended solution, by returning an empty string for any non-date, and an actual `Date` given an actual `Date`. Turns out `IsDate` returns `False` given an error value, a zero, or anything that VBA can't implicitly convert to a date, so `IsDate` is safe enough to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the `.Value` to your function:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example").Cells(rowx, 12).Value = Validate_Date(wbBlank.Worksheets("A15").Range("J15"))
```

And then change your signature so that it takes a `Range` instead of a `String`, and returns a `Variant`:

```
Function ValidateDate(ByVal source As Range) As Variant
```

The function will return a null string pointer (looks like an `""` empty string, but allocates exactly 0 bytes) when `source.Value` isn't a `Date`, and `source.Value` otherwise:

```
    If IsDate(source.Value) Then
        ValidateDate = source.Value ' that's definitely a date
    Else
        ValidateDate = vbNullString ' value was empty, error, or anything "not a date"
    End If
```

By returning an actual `Date`, you're not tampering with the value through implicit `String` conversions.

Note that I removed the underscore from your function name; the underscore has a special meaning in VBA, and when you get into more advanced OOP programming you'll discover that your project stops compiling when you have underscores in public interface member names - so even if you never implement an interface in VBA, adopting and sticking to `PascalCase` naming convention is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting this answer, it did indeed work perfectly - and I feel much more comfortable working with dates in Excel and VBA in general thanks to you. Live long and prosper!